# Read geoJSON from service

Tags: json, leaflet

I'm using leaflet to display user submitted points and polygons to display counts of the points submitted within the polygon.

I've worked with our systems analyst and he created a service that will give me a json object of the polygons. This is what I have so far, I can access the data and log it to the console but nothing is showing on the map

```
var testAreas = [];
$.getJSON("http://server/WildlifeServices/WildlifeMapStats.ashx",
    function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.features,function(i,item){
            console.log(item.geometry.coordinates[0]);
            testAreas.push(L.MultiPolygon(item.geometry.coordinates[0]))
        });
    });
areaGroup = L.layerGroup(testAreas);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON()` is asynchronous, which means that execution of your script will continue past the call to getJSON, and the success handler will be called sometime later, when the geoJSON loads.  Your line of code:

```
areaGroup = L.layerGroup(testAreas);
```

executes before the JSON is loaded.  Try putting that line (and any other lines that depend on that line) into your success handler:

```
var testAreas = [];
$.getJSON("http://server/WildlifeServices/WildlifeMapStats.ashx",
    function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.features,function(i,item){
            console.log(item.geometry.coordinates[0]);
            testAreas.push(L.MultiPolygon(item.geometry.coordinates[0]))
        });
        areaGroup = L.layerGroup(testAreas);
        //additional leaflet related code here
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Didn't solve the problem but definitely helps me to understand more about javascript. PS I'd vote it up, but I don't have enough of a rep yet to do so.